# ReactJS Working with API calls - data changes everytime I use a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my project I'm using data from https://api.randomuser.me/ which basically returns a random person every time you fetch the data.

I've created a component (for the purpose of the question I've simplified it) that returns a first name of person fetched by the API. However, if I use the component twice I get two different names all the time. How can I reuse the component and customise it (using props etc.) while using the same dataset which then refreshes every 10 seconds as in the code below?

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Budgetdata from './Budgetdata.js'
import Caption from './Caption.js'





export default class Apicall extends Component {


    intervalID;
constructor(props) {

  super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading:true,
      person:[],
    random: 0,
    name:"name"};

    }




      async getdata () {

        const url = "https://api.randomuser.me/";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
              var value = Math.round(Math.random())
        this.setState({ person: data.results[0],loading:false,random: value,name:"name"})


      }


      async componentDidMount() {

     this.getdata()

      this.intervalID = setInterval(this.getdata.bind(this), 10000);


      }


      async componentWillUnmount() {

        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
      }






      render = props =>  {

        if (this.state.loading || !this.state.person) {

          return (<div>loading..</div>)
        }
        else
        {

        return(

          <div>{this.state.person.name.first}</div>


        )
        }

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on 
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/ 
await is not well supported at the front end side. I will suggest you to use Axios libraries.

On the other hand, if you need to use a react component twice you could need to use the react component key field as told at:
https://blog.cloudboost.io/key-concept-and-its-necessities-in-react-component-885c18084e59